# How do I launch (pdf) documents with Evince from the Activities Overview in Gnome 3?

Tags: gnome, gnome3, gnome-shell, evince

Evince is already set as the default document viewer.  Clicking on a document while in Nautilus will open Evince to view them.  However, this is not the case when clicking on a document that appears in the [Activities Overview](https://live.gnome.org/GnomeShell/Features#Activities_Overview). Instead, the [Gnome Documents](https://live.gnome.org/Design/Apps/Documents) js application is launched.

Comment: Which version of GNOME 3 are you using?  In 3.6, Evince is what opens the document from the Activities Overview

Answer (score -1):

The search overview displays search results from various "search providers," where each provider is allowed one row of results. If you start typing the name of your PDF, the Documents provider is sorted above the Nautilus ("Files") provider. (I'm not sure how to change this.) If you click on the result under Files instead of under Documents, it should open in Evince instead of Documents.

You can also `sudo rm /usr/share/gnome-shell/search-providers/gnome-documents-search-provider.ini` if you want to get rid of the Documents provider entirely.

January 2016 Update: Nowadays you can disable the Documents search provider using the Search panel in System Settings, or move it down below the Nautilus provider. This is much nicer than manually removing an ini file.